# How to render partial view using url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 and have a prepared url in a view like this:

```
var sectoionUrl = Url.Action("DisplayArticleSection", new { id = sectionId });
```

Is there any helper to render a partial view using prepared **sectionUrl** instead of creating it again via helper:

```
@Html.Action("DisplayArticleSection", new { id = sectionId })
```

?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
@Html.RenderUrl(sectionUrl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom HtmlHelper:

```
public static class RenderUrlHelper
{
    public static void RenderUrl(this HtmlHelper helper, string originUrl)
    {
        var originRequest = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

        if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(originUrl, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            originUrl = new Uri(originRequest.Url, originUrl).AbsoluteUri;
        }

        int queryIdx = originUrl.IndexOf('?');
        string queryString = null;
        string url = originUrl;

        if (queryIdx != -1)
        {
            url = originUrl.Substring(0, queryIdx);
            queryString = originUrl.Substring(queryIdx + 1);
        }

        // Extract the data and render the action.    
        var request = new HttpRequest(null, url, queryString);
        var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
        var values = routeData.Values;
        string controllerName = values["controller"] as string;
        string actionName = values["action"] as string;
        var valuesCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(valuesCollection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => (object)valuesCollection[k]));
        helper.RenderAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
    }
}
```

Some code to test custom HtmlHelper:

TestController:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string title, int number)
    {
        TestModel model = new TestModel { Title = title, Number = number };
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

TestController Index view:

```
@model TestModel

<h1>Title: @Model.Title</h1>
<h2>Number: @Model.Number</h2>
```

TestModel:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Usage in any view:

```
@{
    var actionUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Test", new { number = 123, title = "Hello Url Renderer" });
    Html.RenderUrl(actionUrl);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Following HTML Code To Render partail View Using

```
@Html.RenderPartial("NameOfPartialView")
@Html.Partial("NameOfPartialView")
```

OR

You can create a custom HTML Helper to Create Functionality like,

```
@Html.RenderUrl(sectionUrl)
```

Following url shows step by step how to create Custom HTML Helper.

[Create Custom HTML Helper](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389747/Custom-Strongly-typed-HtmlHelpers-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: I need to get partial view from action, not just render it directly. I hoped there is a built-in helper for that. Since there is no one, I'll try to create the custom helper.